# Pytest print to stdout despite of output capturing

Tags: python, pytest

I am aware that PyTest [captures the output (stdout, stderr, ...) for the tests it executes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/capture-stdout-stderr.html), and that is an awesome feature I want to keep. However, there is some content that I wish to print to the console immediately from my within `conftest.py` file, as general information to the person watching the test execution from their terminal. Using a print statement there does not work, as the output of the `conftest.py` file seems to also be captured, and is only shown if an error happens while executing that file.

Is there a way for me to explicitly bypass this "PyTest output capturing" for a single print statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the bottom of the documentation linked by OP, there is this example:

```
def test_disabling_capturing(capsys):
    print("this output is captured")
    with capsys.disabled():
        print("output not captured, going directly to sys.stdout")
    print("this output is also captured")
```

The content written to `sys.stdout` in the `with capsys.disabled()` context will show up (not prettily) in the pytest results.

Answer (score 1):

To extend on Ian's answer: `capsys` is a function-scoped fixture, meaning it can be used tests, and other function-scoped fixtures, but not higher scoped fixtures, such as a session-scoped.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def my_fxture(capsys):
    with capsys.disabled():
        ("YOLO")
```

The above will result in the following error:

```
ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'capsys' with a 'session' scoped request object, involved factories
```

To get around this, you currently need this hack:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def session_setup_teardown(request):
    capmanager = request.config.pluginmanager.getplugin("capturemanager")
    with capmanager.global_and_fixture_disabled():
        print("YOLO")
```

Answer (score 0):

On Unix you could open the controlling terminal and print to it directly:

```
import os

termfd = open(os.ctermid(), "w")
termfd.write("hello")
termfd.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for that approach, but sadly this does not work for me, I get the error " OSError: [Errno 6] Device not configured: '/dev/tty'". Seems like the test script is not being executed in the context of a terminal?